# Wordpress infect .class-wp-cache.php

Tags: wordpress

I find a problem about an infection in my wordpress
everything points to this type of created files
.class-wp-cache.php
How can I solve this problem?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: If you suspect your site has been "infected", you must nuke the server from orbit, then rebuild from scratch, restore backup of the site - and PATCH EVERYTHING, from OS to Wordpress.  And ensure your code is safe.

Answer (score 0):

If virus has infected many files then it is difficult to fix. Either you can try some antivirus which may fix the issue or have a fresh setup and make it more secure this time. If you don’t have backup and the files are really important then you can download files in your computer and scan. Reupload again but there is chance then it may get infected again the file causing this is not removed after scan.

The things you need to remember.

1. Don’t install the cracked version of any theme or plugins. Most of them contains virus.
2. Make sure to install security plugins like JetPack which helps you to prevent from these types of issues.
3. Change the admin url to something else from default. For example the default is site.com/wp-admin or wp-login.php. You can use plugin to change this url to something custom.
   4.Do some changes in htaccess file to make your website more secure.

This is my email id sanjays442@gmail.com. Please reach out for any help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the following to find where the file exists;

   ```
    find . -name .class-wp-cache.php
   ```
2. Use the following to delete these files from everywhere;

   ```
   find . -name ".class-wp-cache.php" -exec rm -rf {} \;
   ```